# Can I drive from Cuenca to Quito?

Tags: driving, ecuador, quito

On the map, it doesn't show very far. But according to [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/ecuador/the-southern-highlands/cuenca/transport/getting-there-away), a bus ride takes 10 to 12 hours. So I assume the road is very poor. Is it nevertheless possible to drive it on your own with a car? Are any special preparations necessary?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used that road on a public bus in 2009, it wasn't that bad at all. It should be no problem to drive it yourself.

Public buses stop a lot for passengers and also do lunch and toilet breaks, that why they are usually much slower than a private car.

Comment: Actually you can get an executive nonstop direct bus for this journey. One our two stops at most and a bathroom on board. Etiquette apertures to be no number two in onboard bathroom

Answer (score 5):

The road is actually very good. The problem is Andes. It's full of mountains and curves so everyone has to drive slowly.

The bus takes 10 to 12 hours but if you go in your own car it might be less time.

Comment: I think your being harsh the Andes for not facilitating roads...

Answer (score 2):

Even better, it is the Pan-American Highway so it is **the** road and historically the best maintained in Ecuador. It is about an 8-9 hour drive, limited stops by private car. I did it at night once and it was stressful. Ill do it of days from now on. I would take the ***executive*** (Taxi bus on the sign) bus from Quitumbe as it leaves very regularly and enjoy the views. Be sure to sit on the right.

By the way, getting south out of Quito in a private car is a bear that will take many hours for the novice. My advice is "get high left or right" straight away and take these high roads, you do not want to deal with historic Quito and southern Quito traffic through the valley.